# Maven issue in Amazon workspace: Unknown host uk.maven.org`

Tags: maven, maven-clean-plugin

How to resolve the below issue in Amazon workspace? I tried all the sources in Stack overflow, but not resolved while doing Maven clean/install:

`Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to UK (http://uk.maven.org/maven2): uk.maven.org: Unknown host uk.maven.org`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your maven settings.xml.

To get your maven directory open terminal and type the following command `echo %MAVEN_HOME%`

Then open the file under `%MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml` and remove the `UK` mirror

Can you please post your settings.xml file to see its content, this would make the analyses easier